# HTML Tables: Slicky header and the last column auto width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I don't arrive (the [codepen is here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/dQNqBz?editors=1100)) to *auto-width* the last column  in this table(body), that should have sticky headers (check it on a large screen): 
[image]

```css
table.fixed-header {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  width: auto;
}

thead,
tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.colored {
  background: lightgreen;
}

caption {
  caption-side: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Sticky header example</h3>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 colored">
    <table class="fixed-header">
      <caption align="top">Requirements: sticky header, fill the remaining container, 3 rows height and vertical scroll</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id (100px)</th>
          <th>Name (200px)</th>
          <th>Description (auto)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>name 1</td>
        <td>this is a description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>963</td>
        <td>name 2</td>
        <td>this is the second description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>753</td>
        <td>name 3</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>224</td>
        <td>name 4</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>687</td>
        <td>name 5</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>354</td>
        <td>name 6</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>965</td>
        <td>name 7</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>name 8</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>name 9</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is due to `tbody { display: block; }` - by robbing the tbody of its normal `table-row-group` display, you are basically preventing the usual table layout algorithm to work from here on … so cells with `width:auto` _won’t_ grow any more to fill left-over space.

Comment: @misorude thanks, that is great, to know the cause... however, the problem remains... i don't specially need the tbody to be block displayed... but i need sticky headers

Comment: Agree with @misorude comment, why you want to make `tbody` display as `block`?

Comment: @RGhanbari because otherwise overflow won’t work.

Comment: nor position relative, I suppose... @RGhanbari, please see my comment above yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `thead tr` has `display:block`. Add the same rules for the `tbody tr`

```scss
tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: @table_body_height;
    tr {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
```

UPDATE

The OP made this comment:

> the little problem is that the "name" column now does not support the long names to be truncated and ellipsed, if, say for the "name 2" we put "this is a long long column name"

In this case I would put the text inside a `<span>` for example and use the and use the ellipsis on that span:

```css
td span {
      display:block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      max-width:150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

This is the code example:

```css
table.fixed-header {
  width: 100%;
 
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

td span {
  display:block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width:150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}



th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  
}

th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  width: auto;
}

thead,
tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.colored {
  background: lightgreen;
}

caption {
  caption-side: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Sticky header example</h3>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 colored">
    <table class="fixed-header">
      <caption align="top">Requirements: sticky header, fill the remaining container, 3 rows height and vertical scroll</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id (100px)</th>
          <th>Name (200px)</th>
          <th>Description (auto)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>654</td>
        <td>name 1</td>
        <td>this is a description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>963</td>
        <td><span>name 2 this is a very very long name</span></td>
        <td>this is the second description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>753</td>
        <td>name 3</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>224</td>
        <td>name 4</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>687</td>
        <td>name 5</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>354</td>
        <td>name 6</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>965</td>
        <td>name 7</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>name 8</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>name 9</td>
        <td>this is the third description</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just removed the thead or tbody to let the generic `tr {display: block; position: relative;}`

Comment: the little problem is that the "name" column now does not support the long names to be truncated and ellipsed, if, say for the "name 2" we put "this is a long long column name"

Comment: I suppose you understand that the long text could appear anywhere, so, you suppose to put the span in every "td"... could not be so readable in the code (peoplea reading the code could ask theiself what for is that "span"?)

Answer (score 0):

Use followings:

to make last column full width

```
tr{
    display : flex;
}
```

IE doesn't support flex. So, add following

```
td:last-child{
    flex: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To fill the container for 300px height

```
tbody{
    display: inline;
}
```

Full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/j1wfm30d/

Comment: thanks, I don't see any scroll on the tbody and limited height (300px)...